# How to link to dblog filtered by type?

Tags: 7, navigation

In my custom D7 module, I'd like to link to admin/reports/dblog/, however, I'd like to have it filtered by a certain type so when you navigate to that link, the type is already filtered for you.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but the values used to filter that list are put in `$_SESSION['dblog_overview_filter']`. Linking to that page and making it shows the messages filtered by type is only possible if you set that session variable with the right value. Looking at the code of [`dblog_filters()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.admin.inc/function/dblog_filters/7), I get that the following line would cause that list to show the logs about cron tasks.

```
$_SESSION['dblog_overview_filter']['type'] = array('cron');
```

#### References

- [`dblog_overview()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.admin.inc/function/dblog_overview/7)
- [`dblog_filter_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.admin.inc/function/dblog_filter_form/7)
- [`dblog_filters()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.admin.inc/function/dblog_filters/7)