# How to select by default nodes of a content type in admin/content through a link?

Tags: 7, navigation, nodes

I'd like to make a link to `admin/content/`, but when the page was displayed I'd like to have it filtered by a certain content type.

The link can be like this `admin/content/house` so when I click it, the admin/content page is already filtered by house Content Type.

Is this possible?

Is something like this [How to link to dblog filtered by type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/188391/28275) but for the admin/content path.

**Edit:** If I click in a link that can be like this `admin/content/house` I can have in the `admin/page` the Content Types filtered by House, something like this picture

[image]

Comment: What do you mean filter by a content type?

Comment: @Namari I edit with a picture

Comment: It doesn't work with the SYSTEM PATH SETTINGS and the contextual filter on the "admin_views_node". You might have to do the changes in node.admin-content.inc or with a views function.

Comment: @Namari the use of /admin/content/house is just and example, the path can be other.

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I was looking into the "/%" but you can use the parameters with GET as suggested by gapple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're making use of the [Admin Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views), so you can add filter options as GET parameters in the URL: http://localhost/admin/content?type=article

You can also make a clone of the content admin view and modify it. This would allow you to set contextual filters, modify the exposed filter fields, or adjust visible columns to make a more targeted content listing.

Comment: Yes I use the Admin Views module, can you tell me where do you found the answer, just for read a little about this?

Comment: I'm just familiar with views.  If you hover over the table header links, you can view all of the parameters that are set for filters and sorting.

Comment: I see that I can use all the filters :-D